# Sending emails from google sheet with my outlook email

Tags: google-apps-script

So I have an google script for a sheet where a I send emails to customers inside of the google sheet however now the emails come from my gmail adress and I would like to send it from my outlook email, is this possible?
Best regards, Jesper

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Outlook email address as an alias in your main Gmail account. Next, when sending the email using the `GmailApp` or `MailApp` service of Apps Script, specify the alias in the `sendEmail` option as below.

```
 GmailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, textBody, {
   from: "alias@outlook.com",
   name: "Your name"
 });
```